# When isn't it appropriate to use a SQL Index

Tags: sql

I was asked a question today on when wouldn't I want to create a SQL Index on a table.

The only thing I can think of is when you don't need one (i.e. a small table).  That answer doesn't feel right.  Is there a thresh-hold on when I should use an index and when I shouldn't?

Comment: Do you mean "don't want to include an index over this field or on this table", or "don't use this specific index in this given query"?

Answer (score 4):

When not to create an index on the table, there are lots of things to consider.

First, is that there are a lot of possible indexes you could create. For example, you could create an index containing not only every column in the table, but every permutation of the columns (since column ordering in indexes does matter). This could be a huge number of indexes as your column count gets higher.

Every index comes with a number of things that decrease performance in different ways. For example, they may take memory/disk space from what is available. Probably worse than this though, is the fact that indexes need to be updated when the table underneath it is updated. This means that every insert/update/delete in a table, can trigger an index update. As you have more indexes, that's more indexes to update, which can kill performance on your CUD operations, and can kill your server performance if you are doing these often.

Because of this performance impact, you want to avoid 'useless' indexes. Indexes that are used for every query are typically good, but an index used only once a day for a <1s query is probably useless. It's all a tradeoff in attempting to determine which indexes are useful enough to use and whose performance benefits are greater than the performance hits.

Answer (score 1):

You could answer it with the conter question: When do you need an index?

You need an index, if you want to search for entries, to get your results faster. For example if the column is used in a where clause. Of course you could try index everything, but indexing will cause you to use extra memory/hard disk. So you only index columns you use to find your rows.

What rows MySQL for example is reading while trying to find your rows, you can analyze with the [EXPLAIN command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/explain.html).

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb is, to drop all indices except the unique index on the primary key, on small tables (less than about 100'000 rows).

Also, it is not appropriate to use an index, if the column is not for search purpose (e.g. the salary of employees).